# Optimization of MiniZinc model

Tags: optimization, constraint-programming, nonlinear-optimization, minizinc

I have a MiniZinc model which is supposed to find d[1 .. n] and o[1..k, 0 .. n] such that
x[k] = o[k,0] + d[1]*o[k,1] + d[2]*o[k,2] ... d[n]+o[k,n] and the sum of absolute values of o[k,i]'s is minimized.

I have many different x[i] and d[1..n] should remain the same for all of them.

I have a working model which is pasted below, which finds a good solution in the n=2 case really quickly (less than a second) however, if I go to n=3 (num_dims in the code) even after an hour I get no answer except the trivial one (xi=o0), even though the problem is somewhat recursive, in that a good answer for 2 dimensions can serve as a starting point for 3 dimensions by using o0 as xi for a new 2 dimensional problem.

I have used MiniZinc before, however, I do not have a background in OR or Optimization, thus I do not really know how to optimize my model. I would be helpful for any hints on how to do that, either by adding constraints or somehow directing the search. Is there a way to debug such performance problems in MiniZinc?

My current model:

```
% the 1d offsets
array [1 .. num_stmts] of int : x;
x = [-10100, -10001, -10000, -9999, -9900, -101, -100, -99, -1, 1, 99, 100, 101, 9900, 9999, 10000, 10001, 10100];
int : num_stmts = 18;

% how many dimensions we decompose into
int : num_dims = 2;

% the dimension sizes
array [1 .. num_dims] of var int : dims;

% the access offsets
array [1 .. num_stmts, 1 .. num_dims] of var int : offsets;

% the cost function: make access distance (absolute value of offsets) as small as possible
var int : cost = sum (s in 1 .. num_stmts, d in 1 .. num_dims) (abs(offsets[s,d]));

% dimensions must be positive
constraint forall (d in 1 .. num_dims) (dims[d] >= 0);

% offsets * dimensions must be equal to the original offsets
constraint forall (s in 1 .. num_stmts) (
  x[s] = offsets[s,1] + sum(d in 2 .. num_dims) (offsets[s,d] * dims[d-1])
 );

% disallow dimension crossing
constraint forall (s in 1 .. num_stmts, d in 1 .. num_dims) (
  abs(offsets[s,d]) < dims[d]
 );

% all dims together need to match the array size
constraint product (d in 1..num_dims) (dims[d]) = 1300000;

solve minimize cost;

output ["dims = ", show(dims), "\n"] ++
       [ if d == 1 then show_int(6, x[s]) ++ " = " else "" endif ++ 
       " " ++ show_int(4, offsets[s, d]) ++ if d>1 then " * " ++ show(dims[d-1]) else "" endif ++
       if d == num_dims then "\n" else " + " endif  |
   s in 1 .. num_stmts, d in 1 .. num_dims];
```

Comment: What values do you expect for your decision variables `dims` and `offsets`? It might be a good idea to restrict their value domains rather than using `int`. Make sure that the product `offsets[s,d] * dims[d-1]` does not overflow.

Comment: Restricting dims and offsets fixes the problem, i.e., if i make them in a range of -200..200. For this specific problem I know the correct answer is dims=[100,100,130] I can do that. However, in general each of the dims could be as large as 1300000 which leads to integer overflows. Sadly MiniZinc does not seem to support bignum arithmetic.

Comment: With the following strategy instead of "solve minimize cost",  Gecode solve "num_dims = 8" in about 25s: "solve :: int_search(dims, first_fail, indomain_split, complete) minimize cost;" However, all solutions for num_dims upto 8 are cost = 80. Is this correct? If so then it can be used in the model.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the MiniZinc IDE? Have you tried using a different solver?

I was struggling with a problem of dividing `n` random positive integers into `m` groups (`m < n`) where the sum of each group was supposed to be as close as possible to some other number.

When `n` reached about 100 and `m` about 10, it took significantly longer time (30 min+) and the result was not satisfying. This was using the default **Gecode (bundled)** solver. By chance I went through each and everyone of the solvers and found that the **COIN-OR CBC (bundled)** found an optimal solution within 15 s.